# Setting up slurm with 2 different nodes and 2 different partation on 1 physical server

Tags: linux, cluster, cpu-usage, slurm, parallel-computing

I have a requirement for setting up slurm on one physical server, with 2 different partation and 2 main node so, need to have,

partation1 wihich need to have node1 and need to be used by group1 user
partation2 wihich need to have node2 and need to be used by group2 user

in 1 physical server , if anybody could help on this, is this possible , if yes , how?

Comment: You can partition certain servers without having to resort to using VMs. Do you have a Sun E10000 or IBM AS/400 per chance? Otherwise you need to question the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That requirement is nonsense. Placing a node in two partitions is not a problem, but to make two nodes out of it you would need to run two VMs on the server, which is counterproductive for resource scheduling.

I'd argue that even creating two partitions doesn't make much sense.

Check out the accounting options and QOS, which allows you to manage resource usage for different accounts.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but in this case you are the wrong person to do this.